# tikz - use matrix calculation with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to use a matrix calcuation macro in pgfplots but it hang when compile!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\def\M{{2, 1, 1},% 
    {1, 2, 1},%
    {1, 1, 2}}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{F}{3}{%
    \begingroup%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{{\M}[0][0]*#1+{\M}[0][1]*#2+{\M}[0][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{{\M}[1][0]*#1+{\M}[1][1]*#2+{\M}[1][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Z}{{\M}[2][0]*#1+{\M}[2][1]*#2+{\M}[2][2]*#3}%
    \edef\pgfmathresult{(\X,\Y,\Z)}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\newcommand{\T}[3]{
    \pgfmathparse{F(#1,#2,#3)}\pgfmathresult
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {
    \T{0}{0}{50} % <- output coordinates
    \T{0}{50}{0}
    \T{50}{0}{0} };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's the correct way to do such calcuation in pgfplots?

I prefer to use it like: \T(0,0,50) but not sure if it's possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `\addplot` with something slightly different. For instance, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\def\M{{2, 1, 1},% 
    {1, 2, 1},%
    {1, 1, 2}}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{F}{3}{%
    \begingroup%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{{\M}[0][0]*#1+{\M}[0][1]*#2+{\M}[0][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{{\M}[1][0]*#1+{\M}[1][1]*#2+{\M}[1][2]*#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Z}{{\M}[2][0]*#1+{\M}[2][1]*#2+{\M}[2][2]*#3}%
    \edef\pgfmathresult{(\X,\Y,\Z)}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\newcommand{\T}[3]{
    \pgfmathparse{F(#1,#2,#3)}\pgfmathresult
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\edef\mylst{"0,0,50","0,50,0","50,0,0"}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \XX in {0,1,2}
{
\pgfmathparse{{\mylst}[\XX]}
\pgfmathparse{F(\pgfmathresult)}
\ifnum\XX=0
\edef\mycoords{\pgfmathresult}
\else
\edef\mycoords{\mycoords \pgfmathresult}
\fi}
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {\mycoords};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is, of course, not a surface.

Comment: Thanks, 3 point is a triangle,  how can make this triangle to be a surface?

Comment: @lucky1928 You can fill the area between the points with `\addplot3[fill=blue] coordinates {\mycoords};`, say. If you want to have a surface plot with `coordinates`, these coordinates need to be put in using a "matrix form", see p. 124 of the manual v1.16.